# Thread/Process mechanism in Linux

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

My question is regarding the PC register value of which is giving to the created thread.

if I cread a new process with `fork()` the PC value will be copied from the father proccess to the child proccess as the PC value is the next command in the code.

However if I create a new thread as following

```
#include <pthread.h>
int pthread_create(pthread_t *restrict tidp, const pthread_attr_t *restrict attr, void *(*start_rtn)(void), void *restrict arg)
```

with:

```
err = pthread_create(&thready, NULL, &doSomeThing, NULL);
```

I simply give an order for the thread to run with a procedure yet i don't understand from where the created thread gets it's PC value? it's not the father PC for sure. How does the PC value set to the first line of doSomeThing code?

Comment: Its PC value is from the start of the function passed to `pthread_create()` for the thread to run.  When that function returns, the thread exits.

Comment: by "PC register" do you mean the program counter register?  When creating a thread with most packages you specify the function where the thread is to start.

Comment: the register is known as PC or IP. When i create the thead i give pointer to the procedure. I'm trying to understand how the value of the first line in the code of that procedure sets into PC. My question is of HOW it works... The information must be save somewhere and then copied to PC. Where is it saved?

Comment: Mostly the same way how PC is set when the main thread is started.

Comment: The main thread is in fact the proccess so upon creation you don't have this issue. the main thread isn't created by sending your PC somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

(Roughly) It's PC is set to the address of the function you gave. In real it is set to some stub that calls your function. In that stub there is some call to a system routine that sets everything needed to support your thread in the system. How the PC is **exactly** set is very specific to the kernel and hardware. If you feel comfortable with system code, you can browse the Linux kernel sources to look how this is really done.

For example the glibc 2.0 has a `start_thread` function that takes the address of the struct pthread the system built (that routine is the stub). In that function there is a call to some macro `CALL_THREAD_FCT(thread_struct_address)` which purpose is to start running your function. Its definition for i386 platform is :

```
#define CALL_THREAD_FCT (       descr   )   \
({ void *__res;                               \
     int __ignore1, __ignore2;                            \
     asm volatile ("pushl %%eax\n\t"                          \
           "pushl %%eax\n\t"                          \
           "pushl %%eax\n\t"                          \
           "pushl %%gs:%P4\n\t"                       \
           "call *%%gs:%P3\n\t"                       \
           "addl $16, %%esp"                          \
           : "=a" (__res), "=c" (__ignore1), "=d" (__ignore2)         \
           : "i" (offsetof (struct pthread, start_routine)),          \
             "i" (offsetof (struct pthread, arg)));           \
     __res; })
```

See http://fossies.org/dox/glibc-2.20/pthread__create_8c_source.html for example.

Comment: I'm not looking for a specif information but more of the general idea you wrote "PC is set to the address of the function you gave." my following question is: Where is this address saved? is there a table of all entry address of all functions? or if it's computed value - which values are brought for the calculation?

Comment: Look at start_thread function in glibc for example. The call is handled by a call to `CALL_THREAD_FUNCTION(your_address)`. I've never dig into this but I'm sure that you will find how it works for your platform.

Comment: Yes addresses of all functions are known! This is determined at compile time. Look at the table of symbols for any executable (with `nm` tool for example).

Comment: But the table of symbols is gone when compilation ends. I can create a thread with a pointer to function which is unknown during compilation. in running time the correct pointer will be known. How this pointer is translated to the PC register?

Comment: No the table of symbols is stored in the executable file. Even if it is not there when you refer to `func` in the source code the compiler knows the address of the function and then replace the symbol with its value. Yes you can create a thread to a function whose address is unknown at compile-time but this is not done the way you did it! An extern function has an address that is known at link time, so a function with a unknown address at compile/link time is certainly not what you think (I may be wrong of course).